# preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: java, spring, angular, typescript

login(user:any) {
        console.log(user);
        const body = `username=${user.username}&password=${user.password}`;
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        return this.apiService.post(this.url, body, headers);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Goto your server you are trying to send the form information to, to allow `content-type` and also to allow `origin from` the source you are sending information from, e.g am sending information from `http://frontend.com` to `backend.com`, you need to add `http://frontend.com` to your backend `origin` to allow requests from that source, else it won't allow from that origin.

If you are using a backend frame work do well to check their **CORS** settings

Comment: the issue is with your backend server, it's not allowing you to interact with it, your frontend implementation is ok, just contact the backend server or check the configuration to make sure your origin which means ur domain is allowed to send to that server